# Is it safe to enter passwords if I use a local server?

Tags: tls

I have a website that uses https:// out "in the wild".  On my local machine I have my development site.  When I enter usernames and passwords locally unencrypted to my local server is there any security risk?

Answer (score 2):

The only possible risks I can think of are things that may compromise either:

1. Your network - If an adversary is present in your local network, then any unencrypted traffic is trivially sniffed, including your password.
2. Your endpoints - If either the local server or the local client are in an adversary's control, your network traffic is at risk. But at this point you probably have bigger issues to worry about (banking, sensitive documents etc.).
3. Software on the local server - If you are using any 3rd party software that is malicious* you are in trouble, since it has access to the server machine. Perhaps this is a special case of (2) but I'll mention it anyway.

*Edit: I realized that some 3rd party code may send data outside your network for non-malicious purposes which will nonetheless expose your information, although no example comes to mind.